# Look-dev ambient environment not working in Blender 2.8 Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I imported this project from an older version of Blender 2.8 (Janaury release) to the latest May beta release.

Upon doing so, my existing project's ambient background is now a checker background when I switch to look-dev and rendered modes in the EEVEE viewport

[image]

I tried adding an Environment background as you can see in the screenshot (and also switched to rendered view with the eevee viewport) and the background remains as checkers.

Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch from Transparent to "SKY" on Film>Transparency on the Render tab.[image]